# Use of lapply to make tables

Tags: r, apply

I have a very basic question that more experienced coders can probably answer easily.
I have several columns of data. I have turned them into vectors `x1` through `x9`.
I ran the table function as follows:

```
table(x1,x2)
```

**My question is:**

how can I make it so that I have a group of tables such as: `table(x1,x2)`, `table(x1,x3)`, `table(x1,x4)` etc. without repeating typing in the table function (or whatever function I am using; I also need to make bar plots)? I suspect that this involves an apply function but I have been unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lapply` as follows:

```
# First, some sample data
set.seed(1)
yo = data.frame(x1 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace=TRUE),
                x2 = sample(0:2, 20, replace=TRUE),
                x3 = sample(0:2, 20, replace=TRUE),
                x4 = sample(0:2, 20, replace=TRUE))
lapply(2:ncol(yo), function(x) table(yo[, 1], yo[, x]))
```

To get your barplots, you can save that output and use `lapply` and `barplot` together, or you can do something like this:

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 1)) # To plot them all at once...
lapply(2:ncol(yo), function(x) barplot(table(yo[, 1], yo[, x]), 
                                       beside=TRUE, legend=TRUE))
```

Here's an example plot. A lot more customization can be done to "pretty it up" if you need to.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just use lapply to serially pass elements of a list to a function. Using mrdwab's vectors for `table`:

```
x1 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace=TRUE)
x2 = sample(0:2, 20, replace=TRUE)
x3 = sample(0:2, 20, replace=TRUE)
x4 = sample(0:2, 20, replace=TRUE)

lapply(list(x2,x3,x4), table, x1)
[[1]]
   x1
    a b c d e
  0 0 1 2 2 2
  1 1 1 0 2 0
  2 4 2 1 1 1

[[2]]
   x1
    a b c d e
  0 1 2 1 2 1
  1 3 0 0 2 2
  2 1 2 2 1 0

[[3]]
   x1
    a b c d e
  0 2 2 0 3 3
  1 2 2 2 0 0
  2 1 0 1 2 0
```

Barplot doesn't work with character vectors so with ttmaccer's vectors, the same approach works:

```
X1<-1:10
X2<-2:11
X3<-3:12
X4<-4:13
lapply(list(X1,X2,X3,X4), barplot)
```

Comment: I'm not exactly plotting character vectors in my example. I've added an image of the type of plot I *imagined* the OP might want. However, considering that the question itself is pretty vague, I guess we're all correct!

Comment: But, I think I also misread the OP. I didn't see the line where they have turned the "columns" into `vector`s. Oops ;-)